# Register SSL Bindings with BAT File for IIS7

Tags: ssl, iis-7, command-line, batch-file

What is the correct way to run a bat file with the following lines?  I executed them from the `cmd.exe` one by one and worked just fine.  I also need to run it as Administrator.  I would just like to double click my BAT file to have it run instead.

```
appcmd set site /site.name:"assets.test.com" /+bindings.[protocol='https',bindingInformation='*:443:assets.test.com']
appcmd set site /site.name:"api.test.com" /+bindings.[protocol='https',bindingInformation='*:443:api.test.com']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo on
runas /env /user:<username> <path to appcmd>
appcmd set site /site.name:"assets.test.com" /+bindings.[protocol='https',bindingInformation='*:443:assets.test.com']
appcmd set site /site.name:"api.test.com" /+bindings.[protocol='https',bindingInformation='*:443:api.test.com']
pause
```

This should work perhaps after you insert the correct information.